# Where to get MyEclipse 8.6 3.5 Galileo version

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

Where currently in a face where we are progressing from one system version to another. The system is built on Java. In our old version of the system we used MyEclipse 8.6 as the developmenttool.
We installed it from this URL: 
​​http://www.poweredbypulse.com
We then chosed Eclipse 3.5 Galileo
And after that MyEclipse 8.6.
The only problem is this software no longer exist. Where can I find this exact version of MyEclipse now?

Regards

/Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a subscriber, you can get any release of MyEclipse. However, all requests for previous releases are handled by the sales team. Please send an email to sales @ genuitec.com and they will be able to assist you. Be sure to include your name, subscription id, subscription code, MyEclipse version desired, and operating system so they can provide the correct download link without delay.

Note that there have been many releases since 8.6, which have included bug fixes, as well as new features. Generally, existing features continue to be supported, so you should be able to use a later release to ensure full support.

Comment: Both suggestions are excelent. We shose to go with the version that uppgrades the project to MyEclipse 2013 that is our current version. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using the wrong search engine...Google turned this up on 2nd place: http://www.4shared.com/get/A7F_prOh/myeclipse-860-win32.html (.exe for Windows). No idea if this is a legal copy or not.